# TD/IDF in scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, tf-idf

Is there a complete Python 2.7 example about how to use TfidfTransformer (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) to generate TF/IDF for n-grams for a corpus? Look around scikit-learn pages and it only have code snippet (not complete samples).

regards,
Lin

Comment: Hi Lin, [This](https://gist.github.com/abhinavarora/2045f7217da618e096d013810ff64ee9) is a piece of code that I had written for a project. Though it is not well documented but the functions are very well named. Maybe you can look at it.

Comment: Very nice @AbhinavArora, vote up. Quick question2, 1. how is your corpus looks like? If there is any text input sample, it will be great. for me to run without connect to DB, 2. how training/testing related to TD/IDF? I think TD/IDF is just some attribute of term in a specific corpus, should not related to training/testing.

Comment: BTW, why not write a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people as well. :)

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement. I will draft an answer shortly. Answers to your questions are as follows: 
1. The corpus ia a collection of earnings call transcripts of publicly listed companies. Each earnings call transcript is a text article like this http://seekingalpha.com/article/3967201-microsoft-msft-satya-nadella-q3-2016-results-earnings-call-transcript?part=single

Comment: 2. The training and testing come into picture because I am dealing with a classification problem. In the context of TF-IDF, the training set is the corpus on which we learn the IDF weights for each term. Now when we see those terms in the test set, we calculate the TF from their occurrences in the test set, however we use the IDF of the training set while calculating the TF-IDF weight . This allows us to transform test documents in an online fashion, i.e. as they come to our system. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: @AbhinavArora, thanks and vote up for both replies. (1) I see you import nlp packages (spacy.en), are they some 3rd party package which I could use pip to install? (2) Another quick question is, after you get TF/IDF for each term in test document, I think you are using TF/IDF as features, then how do you train your model -- using TF/IDF of each term as features for models? I ask this since, I am thinking if using term (1-gram), or using n-gram, or even using a dictionary is better. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhinavArora, if you could help to comment to my above questions, it will be great. BTW, why not start a reply and I will mark it as answer to benefit other people.

Comment: @LinMa- I have started the reply :-). I am sorry I was quite busy the past 2 days and could not get the time to write this down. For your follow up questions:

1. Yes, [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) is a third party NLP library like NLTK. It has lesser functionality than NLTK , but it is very fast.

Comment: 2. For this application, I used the TF IDF of unigrams to begin with. These TF-IDF vectors are then used for training using a [Regularized Logistic Regression](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/42). You can also build TF-IDF vectors for bigrams, but that will be useful only if you have a big corpus because as you go to higher order N-grams, you will start getting very sparse feature vectors. If you have a sufficiently large corpus, you can try different N-Grams and see which ones give you a good and consistent Cross-Validation performance.

Comment: The rule of thumb here is that as you go to higher order N-Grams, the Bias of your model decreases but your variance will increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For TF-IDF feature extraction, scikit-learn has 2 classes [`TfidfTransformer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer) and [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer). Both these classes essentially serves the same purpose but are supposed to be used differently. For textual feature extraction, scikit-learn has the notion of *Transformers* and *Vectorizers*. The Vectorizers directly work on the raw text to generate the features, whereas the Transformer works on existing features and transforms them into the new features. So going by that analogy, `TfidfTransformer` works on the existing [Term-Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix) features and converts them to TF-IDF features, whereas the `TfidfVectorizer` takes as input the raw text and **directly** generates the TF-IDF features. You should **always** use the `TfidfVectorizer` if at the time of feature building you do not have an existing Document-Term Matrix. At a black box level you should think of the `TfidfVectorizer` as `CountVectorizer` followed by a `TfidfTransformer`.

Now coming to the working example of a `Tfidfectorizer`. Note that at if this example is clear then you will have no difficulty in understanding the example given for `TfidfTransformer`.

Now consider you have the following 4 documents in your corpus:

```
text = [
        'jack and jill went up the hill',
        'to fetch a pail of water',
        'jack fell down and broke his crown',
        'and jill came tumbling after'
       ]
```

You can use any `iterable` as long as it iterates over strings. The `TfidfVectorizer` also supports reading texts from files, about which they have talked in detail in the docs. Now in the simplest case, we can initialize a `TfidfVectorizer` object and fit our training data to it. This is done as follows:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
train_features = tfidf.fit_transform(text)
train_features.shape
```

This code simply `fits` the Vectorizer on our input data and generates a sparse matrix of dimensions `4 x 20`. Hence it transforms each document in the given text to a vector of `20` features, where the size of the vocabulary is `20`.

In the case of `TfidfVectorizer`, when we say `fit the model`, it means that the `TfidfVectorizer` learns the IDF weights from the corpus. 'Transforming the data' means to use the fitted model (learnt IDF weights) to convert the documents into TF-IDF vectors. This terminology is a standard throughout scikit-learn. It is extremely useful in the case of classification problems. Consider if you want to classify documents as positive or negative based on some  labelled training data using TF-IDF vectors as features. In that case you will build your TF-IDF vectorizer using your training data and when you see new test documents, you will simply transform them using the already **fitted** `TfidfVectorizer`.

So if we had the following `test_txt`:

```
test_text = [
        'jack fetch water',
        'jill fell down the hill'
       ]
```

we would build test features by simply doing

```
test_data = tfidf.transform(test_text)
```

This will again give us a sparse matrix of `2 x 20`.**The IDF weights used in this case were the ones learnt from the training data.**

This is how a simple `TfidfVectorizer` works. You can make it more intricate by passing more parameters in the constructor. These are very well documented in the [Scikit-Learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). Some of the parameters, that I use frequently are:

- `ngram_range` - This allows us to build TF-IDF vectors using n gram tokens. For example, if I pass `(1,2)`, then this will build both unigrams and bigrams.
- `stop_words` - Allows us to give [stopwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) separately to ignore in the process. It is a common practice to filter out words such as 'the', 'of' etc which are present in almost all documents.
- `min_df` and `max_df` - This allows us to dynamically filter the vocabulary based on the Document Frequency. For example, by giving a `max_df` of `0.7`, I can let my application automatically remove domain specific stop words. For instance, in a corpus of medical journals, the word *disease* can be thought of as a stop word.

Beyond this, you can also refer to a [sample code](https://gist.github.com/abhinavarora/2045f7217da618e096d013810ff64ee9) that I had written for a project. Though it is not well documented but the functions are very well named.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Abhinav, vote up for your reply and for your comments, `the Vectorizer on our input data and generates a sparse matrix of dimensions 4 x 20`, where to set `4` and `20`? It seems in your code sample, you do not setup such parameters?

Comment: Another question is, for your code sample, `tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
train_features = tfidf.fit_transform(text)`, I see you do not setup parameter n for n-gram, wondering by default, `fit_transform` will only deal with unigram? Thanks.

Comment: The 4 comes because my original corpus in the text variable has 4 documents. The text variable is a list of 4 strings where each string is equivalent to a document.  The 20 was automatically learnt by the Tfidfvectorizer because that is the number of unique unigrams in my corpus(4 documents). There fore the result is 4 (number of documents) x 20 (Vocabulary size).

Comment: Yes by default, the value of n_grams parameter is (1,1). This means that it will build only unigrams. For any integers x and y, such that x<=y, n_grams = (x,y) means that it will generate all x-grams, (x+1)-grams, ..., y-grams.

Comment: @LinMa - Could you please mark this as the accepted answer if it helped clear your doubts :-)

Comment: Sure Abhinav, thanks for the reminder. Mark your reply as answer to benefit other people, I found your reply is more clear than scikit-learn document.